# How can I rewrite Verilog code to remove extra reg?

Tags: verilog

How can I rewrite the code below so that I don't need to have an extra reg mul. I just wanted to take the 32 bits of the resulting 32 * 32 bit multiplication and put it into Result

```
input signed[31:0] Reg1; 
input signed[31:0] Reg2; 
output[31:0] Result; 
reg signed[31:0] Result; 
reg[63:0] mul; 
mul = Reg1 * Reg2; 
Result = mul[31:0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
Result = (Reg1 * Reg2)[31:0];
```